# Database design, wish list and its items

Tags: database-design

I am creating a new database to manage wish lists.

**Solution A:**

Two tables,

- wish_list and
- wish_list_item

**Solution B:**

One table,

- wish_list_with_item

  This would have a wish list item per column, so it will be many columns on this table.

Which is better?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I've only a vague idea of what you're trying to represent here. Please clarify!

Comment: @Thom, I just edited, hopefully this is a lot clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution A is better.  Anytime you try to store collections in columns rather than rows, you're going to run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

solution A is normalized and solution B is not.  In most situations solution A will be better and more flexible.  The major time this is not true is if you are making a summary table of some complex join on large tables for use as a source of quick queries for common questions.  Unless you are building a datamart, this is unlikely to be the case.  Go with solution A.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitly go with the first solution :

- at least, it means you can have as many items you want -- and it'll probably be easier to deal with, on the application side *(think about "deleting an item", or "adding an item", for instance)*
- the second solution absolutly doesn't feel right

Answer (score 0):

The second solution would be better only if you are forced to do a denormalization for the sake of easier caching or if your application grows immensely and you need database sharding. In all other cases I prefer a cleaner design of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Multi - table is complicated, so, single table is practical, simple and thus worth considering. Assuming wish list is a feature of a web site, where some users come, create user account, and then list their wishes it might not be completely obvious, but if you think of it, the question needs to be asked, why would you want to have a header table defining wish list(s) instead of having just the second table, listing wishes. In my mind the need for such an approach indicates that each user will ( likely ) want to have more than one wish list. One for close friends and relatives and one for space ship adventure planned for year 2050 :) Otherwise all the wishes could probably be neatly listed in the wish detail ( second ) table, without the first, for one huge wish list ( let's call it default wish list ), without distinction between wishes, be that something you would like for a present, or plan to accomplish while preparing for space ship adventures ( may all your wishes come true! :) ).

Going back to design of tables, here is considerations. If you do not plan to

1. use wish list for wish list fulfillment
2. add any specifics, details for each of the "whishes" separately

than storing list in something like a long string field allows single table.

If you need 2, than adding second table is justified, but still can be avoided by turning "long string" field into XML column with attributes, where you can pair wished item and some additional comments and / or information.

If you need 1, than two table solution is required, so that a relationship can be established between items on the wish list and anything related to this specific item, be that a gift from close friend or relative, which fulfills the wish, or something like catalog of things stored in yet another table.

If you do use multi - table approach than you will need to be careful so that table listing individual wish items didn't have entries without matching header entry defining the list itself. Usually databases use foreign key to enforce such a relationship. So, the "item" table will need to have a field with a key from the parent table.

Summarizing, it is very likely you will have 2 or 3 tables.
Table 1 - listing user accounts
In the simplest case this table will have a field "my wish list" with long string and / or XML column.
Table 2 - enumerating user wish lists with a key noting related user account.
Table 3 - enumerating wish items, with key from either user account ( if user can have only one wish list ) or Table 2 if each user can have multiple distinct wish lists.

Finally, in theory, users can have shared wish lists. For example, Kate and Simon plan to marry in year 2025. They wish to have a wedding ceremony in a cabin on Vashon Island ( the line is long and last time I checked the place is booked 4 years in advance ). In which case a possibility of 4th table comes along. This table will pare together "users" and "wish lists", to enable joined ownership of wish list.

Hope this helps.

-- cheers!